# why does tf.estimator.DNNRegressor predict negative y value?

Tags: tensorflow

It is so weird for the predict() function in `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor` because it predict negative y value, but the training dataset has no negative y value. I found this when I reduced the value of y by 1000 times, say if y was 12000 before, now I change it to 12. The range of y is `[3-400]` now, but after I did this, the predict() function output some negative values. I didn't set the active function in  tf.estimator.DNNRegressor, so the default active function is relu which range is `[0-max]`, but why it predicts negative value? is some bug in  tf.estimator.DNNRegressor? or is there no active function applied for y? Thank you.

The code is:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import itertools

import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import datasets, metrics
import csv
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

COLUMNS = ["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col10","col11","col12","col13","col14","col15","col16","col17","col18","col19","col20","col21","col22","col23","col24","col25","col26","col27","col28","col29","col30","col31","col32","col33","col34","col35","col36","col37","col38","col39","col40","col41","col42","col43","col44","col45","col46","col47","col48","col49","col50","col51","col52","col53","col54","col55","col56","col57","col58","col59","col60","col61","col62","col63","col64","col65","col66","col67","col68","col69","col70","col71","col72","col73","col74","col75","col76","col77","col78","col79","col80","col81","col82","col83","col84","col85","col86","col87","col88","col89","col90","col91","col92","col93","col94","col95","col96","col97","col98","col99","col100","col101","col102","col103","col104","col105","col106","col107","col108","col109","col110","col111","col112","col113","col114","col115","col116","col117","col118","col119","col120","col121","col122","col123","col124","col125","col126","col127","col128","col129","col130","col131","col132","col133","col134","col135","col136","col137","col138","col139","col140","col141","col142","col143","col144","col145","col146","col147","col148","col149","col150","col151","col152","col153","col154","col155","col156","col157","col158","col159","col160","col161","col162","col163","col164","col165","col166","col167","col168","col169","col170","col171","col172","col173","col174","col175","col176","col177","col178","col179","col180","col181","col182","col183","col184","col185","col186","col187","col188","col189","col190","col191","col192","col193","col194","col195","col196","col197","col198","col199","col200","col201","col202","col203","col204","col205","col206","col207","col208","col209","col210","col211","col212","col213","col214"]

FEATURES = ["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col10","col11","col12","col13","col14","col15","col16","col17","col18","col19","col20","col21","col22","col23","col24","col25","col26","col27","col28","col29","col30","col31","col32","col33","col34","col35","col36","col37","col38","col39","col40","col41","col42","col43","col44","col45","col46","col47","col48","col49","col50","col51","col52","col53","col54","col55","col56","col57","col58","col59","col60","col61","col62","col63","col64","col65","col66","col67","col68","col69","col70","col71","col72","col73","col74","col75","col76","col77","col78","col79","col80","col81","col82","col83","col84","col85","col86","col87","col88","col89","col90","col91","col92","col93","col94","col95","col96","col97","col98","col99","col100","col101","col102","col103","col104","col105","col106","col107","col108","col109","col110","col111","col112","col113","col114","col115","col116","col117","col118","col119","col120","col121","col122","col123","col124","col125","col126","col127","col128","col129","col130","col131","col132","col133","col134","col135","col136","col137","col138","col139","col140","col141","col142","col143","col144","col145","col146","col147","col148","col149","col150","col151","col152","col153","col154","col155","col156","col157","col158","col159","col160","col161","col162","col163","col164","col165","col166","col167","col168","col169","col170","col171","col172","col173","col174","col175","col176","col177","col178","col179","col180","col181","col182","col183","col184","col185","col186","col187","col188","col189","col190","col191","col192","col193","col194","col195","col196","col197","col198","col199","col200","col201","col202","col203","col204","col205","col206","col207","col208","col209","col211","col212","col213"]


LABEL = "col214"


def get_input_fn(data_set, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
  return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
      x=pd.DataFrame({k: data_set[k].values for k in FEATURES}),
      y=pd.Series(data_set[LABEL].values),
      num_epochs=num_epochs,
      shuffle=shuffle)

def get_mae(y_pre, y_target):
    absError = []
    for i in range(len(y_pre)):
        absError.append(abs(y_pre[i] - y_target[i]))
    return sum(absError) / len(absError)

def get_mse(y_pre, y_target):
    squaredError = []
    for i in range(len(y_pre)):
        val = y_pre[i] - y_target[i]
        squaredError.append(val * val)
    return sum(squaredError) / len (squaredError)

training_set = pd.read_csv("train.csv", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)
test_set = pd.read_csv("test.csv", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS) 
predict_set = pd.read_csv("predict.csv", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS) 


feature_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in FEATURES]
regressor = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols, hidden_units=[250, 200, 100, 50], model_dir="./model")

regressor.train(input_fn=get_input_fn(training_set), steps=8000)

ev = regressor.evaluate(input_fn=get_input_fn(test_set, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False))
loss_score = ev["loss"]
print("Loss: {0:f}".format(loss_score))

predict = regressor.predict(input_fn=get_input_fn(predict_set, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False))
y_predict = predict_set[LABEL].values.tolist()
print(type(y_predict))
print(y_predict)
list_predict = list(predict)
print(type(list_predict))
y_predicted = []
for i in range(len(list_predict)):
    y_predicted.append(list_predict[i]['predictions'][0])
print(y_predicted)

fileObject = open('time_prediction.txt', 'w')
for time in y_predicted:
        fileObject.write(str(time))
        fileObject.write('\n')
fileObject.close()

mae = get_mae(y_predict, y_predicted)
mse = get_mse(y_predict, y_predicted)
print("Mean Absolute Error:" + str(mae) + " Mean Squared Error:" + str(mse))

#mae = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_predict, list_predict)
#print(mea)
```

This is the 3 data records of the dataset:

> 2399.998,4,100,100,0,0,1,10,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,0,0,2,44,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,1,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,4,13,4,0,11,14,15,10,8,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,364,123428,1397595,16772133,56,103,16772153,22,22,11
>
> 1919.9984,2,30,30,0,0,1,10,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,0,0,0,38,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,1,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,12,2,0,9,14,10,9,2,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,17525535,34347257,1397595,5590711,16698805,103,5913257,896853,1190468,25
>
> 479.9996,2,60,60,0,0,1,10,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,0,0,0,38,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,1,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,12,2,0,9,14,10,9,2,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,17525535,34347257,1397595,5590711,16698805,103,5913257,896853,1190468,168

The last column is y.

Comment: Please post your code snippet, I want to see how your dataset looks like, and how you framed your solution using `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor`

Comment: As a debugging exercise, what if all of your training targets have the same positive value?  Can you get it to always predict that number?  You also might find that some data normalization keeps your problem better-constrained, i.e. shift your features and targets by the mean and divide by the width of the distribution so that each feature is mostly distributed between -1 and 1.  Then re-scale your predictions afterword.

Comment: @JoshuaR. Thanks for your recommendation. Do you mean normalizing data will resolve this problem? Even though it will, this still doesn't make sense because relu should not be such result, there must be something wrong in the DNNRegressor

Comment: @xiaosu, mostly the normalization is a side comment (though possible related) since it sounds like you're not doing that - but good practice.  You should try to understand the strange behavior that you see; I'd recommend trying produce a simpler example of DNNRegressor behaving strangely (like seeing if you can train it to be a positive constant).

Comment: @EkabaBisong, thanks, the code has posted

Comment: I'm really trying to make sense of the code and data. What do you mean by `columns` and `features`, and then what is now `training_set` and `test_set`?
Which exactly is the dataset that you want to train the model on?